# Mobile Application:Secure URL and AccessToken

Tags: android, salesforce

I am new to Salesforce. I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. In my application, I am sending a url and access token to retrieve data from the salesforce. How do i protect this url and access token. How do people try to hack this url and access token during security  review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use some encryption algorithm to send data to server and from server side they will decrypt it in same way as u had encrypt the data.